# Ensure standard library linked to boost matches mongo C++ driver's

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, abi, mongo-cxx-driver

I want to install MongoDB C++ client. I read in its [manual](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-and-Compile-the-Legacy-Driver) that:

> On systems offering multiple C++ standard libraries, you must ensure
>   that the standard library linked into boost matches that linked into
>   the driver.

My O.S is ubuntu 14.04.
Does the above quote applies to my system?
How do I ensure which standard library is linked into the boost which I installed apt-get install libboost-all-dev?
In case libboost-all-dev is not linked against c++11, do I need to build from source?
My application is going to be using multi threading, do I need to make sure boost, mongodb C++ client and other libraries are linked using some multi threaded flag?

Comment: Ok, I realize now that standard library means whether the system have libstdc++ or libc++. Which is not applicable to ubuntu but rather to mac.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is not a system that is offering multiple C++ standard libraries. e.g. in ubuntu you would use GPLish libstdc++ and don't need the libc++.

I don't know how to tell whether the boost package for ubuntu was linked with c++11 but it must have since once I matched my mongo to be linked with c++11 it - mongo stopped crashing.

So if you are using ubuntu and want to use mongo legacy c++ driver you should build mongo with the c++11 flag.
for example:

```
scons --c++11 install
```